# gtk# have a popup add window update the liststore and gtktreeview of calling window

Tags: c#, gtk#

I am new to GTK# and C# and have gone through the available tutorials and proceeding well, however I have a question I cannot find an answer to.

I have built a window with a GTKTreeview in it that uses a ListStore for the Model. I have written a add window that pops up when an add button is pressed. The add window adds the data to the database but I would like to be able to updated the liststore and gtktreeview window with the new added data.

The add window clears the entry fields and refocuses the text entry so you can do multiple adds before closing the add window. I would like to update the calling window with the gtktreeview each time the add button is pressed but am not sure how to go about it.

I hope this makes sense and hope that someone can help a newcomer to both c# and gtk#.

Thanks,
Anthony

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to pass the add window a reference to the calling window, and give the calling window suitable methods for the add window to call to accomplish these updates. You could also pass the relevant data structures directly to the add window if you don't mind having something outside the calling window modifying them.

Comment: Thanks Matthew I have got it working after some trial and error.

I made a private static ListStore variable in the treeview window and passed that by reference to the add window.

In the add window I added a private ListStore variable and had the add window constructor assign it the liststore that I passed by reference then when the onaddbuttonclicked code executes I appendvalues to to liststore and all the treeview windows update as expected.

Thanks again,
Anthony